# Need to select every 4th cell in a given Column ( Column E)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have over 1200 cells in column E.
This was originally a quiz with 4 options, so for each question there are 4 answers now. I need to select every 4th cell, then every 4th starting from the second entry ( thats option 2), and again for option 3 and 4. I need to select every 4th cell in column E. How do I do that? My opt 1 is Column F,op2 is column G and so on.

Comment: This is hard to understand how your data is arranged and what you are trying to do. Are you saying the data you want to select is in columns `E`, `F`, `G` and `H`, and you want to select the 4th row of those columns, then every 4th row after that? In other words, you would end up with `E4:H4`, `E8:H8`, `E12:H12` and so forth selected. Am I right?

Comment: When you say "select", do you mean highlight or shade?

Answer (score 0):

Using the indirect formula you can set the row separately from the column so you could use

Formula returns row 1,5,9

> =indirect("E" & row(A1)*4-3)

Formula returns row 2,6...

> =indirect("E" & row(A1)*4-2)

and so on.